# Upper bound on the distance between two distinct orthonormal vectors

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises

I need to prove that if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are distinct vectors of an orthonormal set then $|| \phi - \psi|| \leq \sqrt{2} $.

Going by the definition of norm, $|| \phi - \psi||^2$ is the inner product $\langle\phi - \psi|\phi - \psi\rangle$. By linearity of inner products I get $\langle \phi|\phi\rangle - \langle \phi|\psi\rangle - \langle \psi|\phi\rangle + \langle \psi|\psi\rangle$, which equals $2$ by orthonormality conditions. And thus, $|| \phi - \psi|| = \sqrt{2} $.

But how does one get the $\leq$ relation instead of $=$ above?

Comment: If $x=y$ then $x \leq y$.

Comment: Yes its true but are there conditions under which strictly less than relation is achieved.

Comment: Can you point to the problem set where you have to achieve the strict less than relation?

Comment: @Rammus: There is stated that the vectors are distinct, so I would not consider case when $x=y$.

Comment: @MartinVesely $x$ and $y$ are numbers (or more generally any elements of a poset). I was trying to communicate, $\sqrt{2} \leq \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to prove that, given any pair of vectors  $\psi,\phi$ in an orthonormal set, their distance is $\le\sqrt2$? If so, you already did: you either pick two distinct (and thus orthonormal) vectors, or you get twice the same vector, in which case the distance is obviously smaller than $\sqrt2$

Comment: @glS the problem is that the question statement says that $\psi$ and $\phi$ are _distinct_ vectors - otherwise I agree with you